# Binary matrix from association data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert an association matrix of species into a binary matrix of 0 & 1 showing association or no association.

The original df looks like this:

Galler, Synergus

Acraspis_pezomachoides, Synergus_oneratus_1201_003_2
Acraspis_pezomachoides, Synergus_erinacei_602_003_1A
Acraspis_erinacei,  Synergus_campanula_442_002_3C
Acraspis_erinacei,  Synergus_oneratus_442_002_2D
Acraspis_villosa,   Synergus_1206_004_3
Disholcaspis_quercusglobulus,   Synergus_punctata_555_019_35B
Disholcaspis_quercusglobulus,   Synergus_oneratus_546_019_22

I am trying to change this into a matrix that shows gallers as row names and synergus as col names. The end product needs to look like this:

Synergus_oneratus_1201_003_2,
Synergus_erinacei_602_003_1A,
Synergus_oneratus_52_3_3b

Acraspis_pezomachoides  1   1   1
Acraspis_erinacei   0   0   0
Acraspis_villosa    0   0   0
Disholcaspis_quercusglobulus    0   0   0
Disholcaspis_quercusmamma   0   0   0
Druon_ignotum   0   0   0
Atrusca_quercuscentricola   0   0   0
Philonix_nigra  0   0   0
Andricus_quercusstrobilanus 0   0   0
Andricus_kingi  0   0   0

I know its difficult to explain some of this in words and its even harder to show. If you have any questions or need actual pictures let me know. I've done all of this manually already but I am trying to automate the pipeline

Comment: Do you need `table(df1)`

Comment: Can you add your data by editing your question and including the output from `dput(df)`?

Comment: I knew the answer to this was going to be rudimentary. I believe table(df) works. let me input it into the package I am using to analyze this data and see if it'll accept the format

Comment: i regret to inform you all that table(df) works just fine and I have been overthinking this problem for hours. rip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are pivoting wide

```
(df_ <- data.frame(
  l=letters[1:12],
  L=rep(LETTERS[1:4],each=3)
)  )

library(tidyverse)

df_ |> mutate(dummy=1L) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from="L",
            values_from = "dummy",
            values_fill = 0L)
```